# background shows through table cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with a decorative border with the content in the middle. So I've created a 3x3 table with images in all the outer cells and content in the middle cell. The code looks like this:

```
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="60%">
    <tr>
        <td style="background:url(box_topleft.png);background-repeat:no-repeat transparent;width: 45px; height: 125px"></td>
        <td style="background:url(box_topmiddle.png);repeat-x; height: 125px"></td>
        <td style="background:url(box_topright.png);background-repeat:no-repeat transparent;width: 45px; height: 125px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url(box_middleleft.png);background-repeat:repeat-y;width: 45px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color:white">text</td>
        <td style="background-image:url(box_middleright.png);background-repeat:repeat-y;width: 45px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background:url(box_bottomleft.png);background-repeat:no-repeat transparent;width: 45px; height: 125px"></td>
        <td style="background:url(box_bottommiddle.png);repeat-x; height: 125px"></td>
        <td style="background:url(box_bottomright.png);background-repeat:no-repeat transparent;width: 45px; height: 125px"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Everything lines up and looks great on a white body background. But when there is another color background or a background image for the body, the background color peeks between the cells.

A simpler example, given a blue body background, the following example should just be a white rectangle:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="60%">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:blue; width:10px; height:100px"></td>
    <td style="background-color:blue; height: 100px">text</td>
    <td style="background-color:blue; width:10px; height:100px"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But the browser shows blue lines between the TD.

This happens in Chrome, partially in Firefox and not at all in IE. The cell padding and spacing is already zero, so I don't know why there's any background visible between the cells in Chrome. Is there anything else I need to do?

I've also added the following without success:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Thanks. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you produce a codepen or some debuggable code?

Comment: Off the type of my head, I would try putting the table in a div, set the background image to the div, then set the table background to transparent. Or put the complete image on the table tag instead of cutting it up.

Comment: My apologies. This is literally my first post on stackoverflow and I haven't coded for about 10 years, so I have no clue what codepen is. If it's the { } script tag when making my first post, the example I made actually DID NOT show any background color peeking through. That's what makes it frustrating.

Comment: With regards to chopping up the background image, it allows the decorative border to scale nicely regardless of the contents of the middle cell. So I can reuse the same table code/border images every time regardless of the middle content size.